# Visual Studio 2019 - Authentication - Cloud Explorer - Reenter Credentials

Tags: azure, visual-studio, authentication

I want to use the Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio 2019. The subscriptions are displayed and I can work with most of them. But it does not work for certain subscriptions and I get the the prompt to reenter my credentials. But doing so does not resolve the issue.

[image]

[image]

I also tried to log out and log in again with my account in Visual Studio. Also didn't help.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the following steps what in the end resolved the issue:

- Remove the account from Visual Studio and then close all Visual Studio instances
- Log out from Azure CLI via `az logout`
- Log out from Azure PowerShell via `Disconnect-AzAccount`
- Clear Windows Credentials via the Windows Credential Manager
- Delete the folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.IdentityService`
- Log in to Azure CLI again via `az login` and `az account set -s <subscription id>`
- Log in to Azure PowerShell again via `Login-AzAccount -TenantId <tenant id> -SubscriptionId <subscription id>`
- Start Visual Studio. I was already logged in, but if necessary log in again with your account.

It might be that not all steps are required but overall it resolved the issue.

**EDIT**

It just happened again and what fixed it was to log in to the right tenant and subscription in Azure Powershell via `Login-AzAccount -TenantId <tenant id> -SubscriptionId <subscription id>`.